# CMake, Xcode and Unix Makefile

Tags: xcode, makefile, cmake

I was using classic Unix Makefile generator until I found a webpage explaining CMake could produce a nice xcode project file using "cmake -G Xcode" so I ran that command in my source directory and I get a nice xcode project. This is great but I'm facing some drawback and was wondering if there are solutions to these :

- now I can't build out of tree using unix makefiles (I use to run cmake ../myproj in a build dir and then make command) this doesn't work anymore (I suppose temp files in the project dir are responsible)
- some of my headers are generated by cmake (myproj.h.in became myproj.h and is include in some tests for example) but I can't find those files in the xcode project I get.

Thanks in advance for any good advice on how I can combine xcode project and unix makefile to be able to use both.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the answer by myself (I mean asking the good person) :

Use 2 separate build directories for each type of build files. This will ensure each build directory has the correct build files and generated files for its use.

In the add_executable() command, in addition to the source files also include the headers and generated headers for those to show up in Xcode.

Answer (score 3):

You can use xcodebuild to still have a proper Xcode project and build it from the command line/shell script/Makefile, e.g.

```
xcodebuild -project MyProject.xcodeproj -target MyTarget -configuration Release
```