# Is it possible to automatically generate Xcode projects?

Tags: xcode, scons

Simple question. Are there any tools for generating Xcode projects from the command line? We use SCons to build our cross-platform application, but that doesn't support intrinsic Xcode project generation. We'd like to avoid creating the project manually, since this would involve maintaining multiple file lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your question should be "Is there a way to generate an XCode project from a SCons one?". I suppose, by your asking and by reading the others, that the answer is 'no'.

[SCons people](http://www.scons.org/contact.php) should know it better. I think they will be happy if you contribute a SCons Xcode project generator.

In the meantime you may choose to switch to CMake or to create your XCode project by hand that, given a good source tree organization, may be the best pragmatic solution.

Answer (score 5):

Look at [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/). You can generate XCode projects from it automatically. I found a previous StackOverflow question about its usage [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751837/cmake-xcode-and-unix-makefile). To get it to generate an XCode project, you use it as such:

```
CMake -G xcode
```

Comment: Yeah, we're trying to avoid converting the project to CMake... I guess we could generate a CMakeLists.txt file from SCons, or maybe not ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use premake (http://industriousone.com/premake) to generate Xcode projects. It can also generate Visual Studio projects.

Answer (score 2):

For the benefit of anyone who lands on this question, I’ve actually just pushed [an Xcode project file generator for SCons](https://bitbucket.org/al45tair/scons-xcode) up to Bitbucket.

Comment: +1 - Interesting. Any chance this could be made compatible with Homebrew? Would also be nice if it could optionally start with .swift files.

Comment: @TommieC. The generator doesn't care about source file contents at all (so Swift sources will Just Work™). The generator deliberately constructs external build system targets that run SCons, so the build won't deviate from what's specified in the SConstruct file. I don't think SCons itself supports Swift out of the box, though you could write a builder for it easily enough if you're competent in Python. As for Homebrew support, I don't know what you'd want; all you need to install the generator is to copy a file — I can't see how brew helps.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on this ~ I am an agnostic coder, so I will look at the Python options. A brew package would make the code "managed" and makes updates transparent, while likely increasing the scope of the user base.

Comment: @TommieC. I suppose you could make a brew package to install it in one of the system-wide `site_scons` directories, but since the invocation has to happen from the SConstruct file I rather imagine that individual project maintainers will want to make a project-level `site_scons` and stick it in there. brew wouldn't help with that, and installing system-wide would just make it a build dependency that everyone would have to install; better to include the tool with the relevant sources I think (also means there are no versioning problems, unlike what happens with autotools sometimes).

Answer (score 1):

qmake in the Qt toolchain generates Xcode projects. You can at least download it and take a look at its source [here](http://www.qtsoftware.com/downloads) (LGPL).

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a XCode project using the python based build system called [waf](https://waf.io/). You need to [download and install waf](https://waf.io/book/#_download_and_installation) with the xcode6 extension:

```
$ curl -o waf-1.9.7.tar.bz2 https://waf.io/waf-1.9.7.tar.bz2
$ tar xjvf waf-1.9.7.tar.bz2
$ cd waf-1.9.7
$ ./waf-light --tools=xcode6
```

That will create a `waf` executable which can build your project. You need to configure how to generate your XCode project inside a file called `wscript` that should reside in your project folder. The `wscript` file uses Python syntax. Here's [an example](https://gitlab.com/ita1024/waf/blob/master/playground/xcode6/wscript) of how you could configure your project:

```
def configure(conf):

    # Use environment variables to set default project configuration
    # settings
    conf.env.FRAMEWORK_VERSION = '1.0'
    conf.env.ARCHS = 'x86_64'

    # This must be called at the end of configure()
    conf.load('xcode6')

# This will build a XCode project with one target with type 'framework'
def build(bld):
    bld.load('xcode6')
    bld.framework(
        includes='include',

        # Specify source files.
        # This will become the groups (folders) inside XCode.
        # Pass a dictionary to group by name. Use a list to add everything in one
        source_files={
            'MyLibSource': bld.path.ant_glob('src/MyLib/*.cpp|*.m|*.mm'),
            'Include': bld.path.ant_glob(incl=['include/MyLib/*.h', 'include'], dir=True)
        },

        # export_headers will put the files in the
        # 'Header Build Phase' in Xcode - i.e tell XCode to ship them with your .framework
        export_headers=bld.path.ant_glob(incl=['include/MyLib/*.h', 'include/MyLib/SupportLib'], dir=True),
        target='MyLib',
        install='~/Library/Frameworks'
    )
```

There are a bunch of settings you can use to configure it for your project.

Then to actually generate the XCode project, `cd` into your project folder where the `wscript` is and run your `waf` executable like

```
$ ./waf configure xcode6
```

Comment: But when I run ./waf build I get an error in the python - AttributeError: 'BuildContext' object has no attribute 'framework'

Comment: try writing "./waf xcode6" instead of "build". And remeber to run the configure first also, i.e. "./waf configure". @Mark. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

A promising alternative to CMake which can generate Xcode projects is [xmake](https://github.com/xmake-io/xmake). I haven’t tried it yet, but it looks good from the documentation.

Install xmake, create a simple project file (xmake.lua):

```
target("test")
    add_files("src/*.cpp")
```

Then you can either do a command-line build:

```
xmake
```

or create an Xcode project:

```
xmake project -k xcode
```

Note that currently xmake seems to invoke CMake to generate the Xcode project, although they say they plan to add native Xcode project generation at some point.

Answer (score -2):

You could use Automator to generate them for you.

I checked and there is no prebuilt action.
Therefore you would have to record your actions with Automator to do this.

Comment: Just checked out Automator, I'm not sure its what I'm looking for since it uses the GUI to perform operations. I was thinking more like a command based approach... Thanks anyway.