# Generate xcode project with waf

Tags: c++, xcode, waf

How I can generate xcode project with [waf](https://code.google.com/p/waf/)?

I see the xcode.py it says use ./waf configure xcode but it dose not work and says xcode function not found error.

I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put

```
opt.load('xcode')
```

into the options definition of your wscript. And, maybe more importantly, your waf needs to be generated, such that this module is actually available. This can be achieved for example, by creating waf with:

```
./waf-light --make-waf --prelude='' --tools=xcode
```

For details see section 1.1.2 of the [waf book](http://docs.waf.googlecode.com/git/book_17/single.html#_download_and_installation), which explains how to build waf from source.

Comment: I called "./waf configure xcode" and then a xcode project was generated. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

There is now a [xcode6 tool](https://gitlab.com/ita1024/waf/merge_requests/1648) for waf which generates project for XCode 6, 7, 8, and 9.

You can find an example of how it works that I wrote in another answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114140/is-it-possible-to-automatically-generate-xcode-projects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42445780/577421)