# Generate an xcodeproj

Tags: xcode, automation, applescript

I know this might sound a bit strange but I'd need to generate a xcodeproj automatically.
Basically scanning the filesystem and adding certain files to the project and to a specific target.

The main reason behind this, is that I work in an zero IDE environment. Thus, we have our own build system and source files are added and removed all the time.

I could use "create folder references for any added folders". However, xcode won't ever parse source files if they aren't part of any target. So, no symbols, no code completion...

To me, my only option would be to "auto-update" my xcodeproj with a script...

Thanks in advance for your inputs!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Cmake](http://www.cmake.org/) is one option (see this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751837/cmake-xcode-and-unix-makefile)) and there's also [Scons](http://www.scons.org/wiki/MacOSX) which I think can generate Xcode projects.  There's also Qt's qmake which can generate the project files, but this is probably overkill unless you're using full Qt.

Answer (score 2):

You can either user AppleScript (or anything OSA-compatible) to automate the process of creating the project in Xcode itself, or you could look at [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/), which is able to generate Xcode project files.